# An error occurred while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Any idea how to fix this?

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p194 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I had this issue after updating to a newer patch version of ruby.  Unfortunately the header files gem "debugger-ruby_core_source" was locked in to an earlier version in the Gemfile.lock so it didn't have the required header files.

All you need to do is update that gem by doing:

```
bundle update debugger-ruby_core_source
```

You should be able to bundle install afterwards.

If you aren't using bundler then just install the latest version before trying to install debugger:

```
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
```

Comment: tyvm dude... wasted like 30mins running in circles til I found your answer

Comment: Same error for me, even after installing `debugger-ruby_core_source`

`gem install debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.5.gem
Successfully installed debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.5
1 gem installed

C:\RubyGems\lib\debugGems>gem install ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.29.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.29.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no`

Comment: @Arpit this fix is for the gem 'debugger' [github](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) - not sure it works with windows but you could give it a try....

Comment: Yeah.. already installed the `debugger` gem. Now, the question is - How to tell this to RubyMine? (it's still searching for `ruby-debug-base19x`)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to switch to using ruby `p125`, e.g.

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p125
rvm use 1.9.3-p125 --default
```

I had ruby 1.9.3-p194 and apparently that doesn't have the debug/linecache I need.

Comment: This was a quick hack that I'd no longer recommend as you want to be able to keep moving ruby and rails version forward.  Using the above fix by Luke is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

open  terminal, go to project directory and remove Gemfile.lock using

```
 rm Gemfile.lock
```

to remove Gemfile.lock and run

```
bundle install
```

which will create new Gemfile.lock so its easy to do it :)

worked for me.

Comment: You can do "bundle update" instead of removing the Gemfile.lock - this is effectively doing the same thing.